# Is there an Ant equivalent to the Maven JXR report

Tags: java, ant

I have an Ant bulid that generates various analysis reports such as checkstyle and PMD.  I'd like to link to the java source code in the reports in a similar way to what can be achieved by using the JXR plugin in a Maven build.

How can I build the source xref html using Ant?

Answer (score 0):

If Ant is your main build tool you can use the Maven Ant Tasks on a minimal pom.xml that only creates the JXR report.